# How does twitter allow certain people to perform mass manipulation?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, personality

Recently we have seen many billionaires doing mass manipulation with the use of twitter.
Is there any line of research of the categories of manipulation these people are doing on twitter?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  You said, *"Recently we have seen many billionaires doing mass manipulation with the use of twitter."* Can you please give a couple of examples along with evidence to show that mass manipulation is occurring?

Comment: @ChrisRogers Elon Musk manipulating the stock price of several cryptocurrencies and companies